# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.csv' in VS Code

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code

I was trying to read from a .csv file and wrote a very basic code.

```
import csv

with open('Test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

Both the test.csv and my .py file is in the same directory. For some reason when I run this in vs code, it pops up an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.csv'

But the same code works perfectly fine with sublime text. I'd like to use Vs code for my future projects so it will be helpful if someone can solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: is it "test.csv" or "Test.csv"?

Comment: Print `os.getcwd()` and verify if you are in the directory in which you think you are.

Comment: program can run code in different folder then you expect and code can't find other files. You can use `/full/path/to/Test.csv` or you can search question about getting script full path using `sys.path.dirname(sys.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))`

Comment: in launch.json you can set the cwd

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

One: Change "open('Test.csv', 'r')" to "open('xxx\xxx\Test.csv', 'r')", set the absolute path of 'Test.csv' file.

Two: In launch.json file setting '"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/xxx/the folder which contains the Test.csv",' in "configurations".
It looks like the first solution is more suitable.

Explains:

${cwd} - the task runner's current working directory on startup. The default setting of 'cwd' is the "${workspaceFolder}".

Answer (score 0):

I think VS Code will often run scripts in the Python install location. You can change this. Click the gear icon on the bottom left of VS Code.

And then click settings.

A search bar will come up. Type in "Execute in File Path" and click the checkmark or set that to true.

Reload VS Code and you shouldn't have to open VS Code in the folder each time you want to run a script without specifying the absolute file path.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the code runner extension? if so, then make sure the folder you are opening is the one containing the Test.csv file.

```
dir1/
 |_dir2/              <-make sure you open this folder
    |_script.py
    |_Test.csv
```

Basically, make sure your working directory from where you execute the python file has Test.csv in it.

Comment: Since you cannot comment on other posts, you have to earn enough reputation.

Comment: i know that, thats why i put an answer

Comment: You should not post comments as answers. They will be deleted, and your rep will further decrease for breaking the rules.